# vb.net - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable'

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, datatable

So I have a button that deletes a specified user added datatable from a dataset.Lets say there is a user added table at index 5 to be deleted. There are 4 typed tables which always remain in the dataset. The issue is when the button is clicked the correct table is removed but then I get an error at `MainDataSet.Tables.RemoveAt(5)` of "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'calendarDataTable' ". calendar is the name of the first typed table in my dataset. I did not have this issue until I went from programmatically adding the tables to adding them in the designer since they never change. I'm scratching my head because I don't know if the `CollectionChanged` event that is triggered from calling `RemoveAt` is causing the issue or what. It is just strange because it works in that the table gets removed then crashes and burns...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If MainDataSet.Tables.CanRemove(MainDataSet.Tables(5)) Then
       MainDataSet.Tables.RemoveAt(5)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: are you _positive_ that the error occurs on `MainDataSet.Tables.RemoveAt(5)` and not someplace else (like rebinding your datasource)?

Comment: That is either not the correct error message or it is not happening in that code. The post mentions 5 tables (0, 1, 2, 3} *always remain in the dataset* then the user table with Index 5 - you are missing a table

Comment: I updated my original post to clarify a bit better. There is definitely a table at the index I want to delete. I will look at the stack and post my findings.

Comment: It has something to do with the static datatables being typed instead of added at runtime. I deleted the tables from the designer and added the code back to forms load event to create the tables and everything works great. Guess I will stick that until I can get a little more clarity on the underlying error at `MainDataSet.Tables.RemoveAt(5)`. I looked at the stack and there traces in MainDataSet.Designer.vb

Comment: Paste the code for the `CollectionChanged` event.  Think of where it would try to `cast` to `calendarDataTable`